# Laravel 9: Trait with validation

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I created a trait to use with a controller. The controller should start the trait function, which validates its input and then does a thing.

Inside the FooController.php:

```
[..]
$do_stuff = $this->create_stuff($input);
```

The trait:

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Traits;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    [..]
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    
    trait Foo
    {
       public function create_stuff(Request $input)
        {
            // validation part
            $validatedData = $input->validate([
                    'Value' => 'required|numeric',
                    ]);
            // end of validation part

    [..]
```

Everything works fine without the validation part but as soon as I add it I get the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\\Http\\Controllers\\FooController::create_stuff() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of stdClass given,[..]
```

I understand the $input is a 'normal' (?) PHP object and it seems the validation only works with 'request' objects, so how can I make this work?

Comment: `public function create_stuff($input)` if you want it to accept everything. By doing `Request $input` in your code, you've told PHP your function only accepts a Request object.

Comment: You understand correctly; `$input` is currently a `stdClass` object, but you're defining it as `Request $input`. You'd have to call it via something like `create_stuff(request())` (or a variable `$request`, etc), or use a manual validator, which accepts a plain array of input to validate: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators. Oh, and @ceejayoz `create_stuff($input)` would fail for a `stdClass` or `array`, as `$input->validate(...)` would be invalid (unless this `stdClass` has a `validate` method of course)

Comment: @TimLewis Fair; I was focused on the immediate reason for OP's error. You're right they're going to encounter additional issues along the way with my answer.

Comment: I see, thanks guys @TimLewis and ceejayoz.  I'll go with a manual validator then.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please don't create a trait for validation create a request for validation using PHP artisan

```
PHP artisan make:request Your_request_name
```

and inside your request add your validations like this

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'sponsor_name' => ['required', 'string'],
            'sponsor_type' => ['required', 'string'],
            'mobile' => ['required', 'string'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string'],
            'nationality' => ['required', 'string'],
            'sponsor_issued_from' => ['required', 'string'],
            'sponsor_issued_date' => ['required', 'date'],
            'sponsor_address' => ['required', 'string'],
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

then inside your request add your validations
after that just call your request in your controller function

for example

```
public function (Your_request_name $request)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The trait is not primarily for validation tho, I just thought I validate the inputs first. But this looks interesting, I'll take a look into it, thx.